# How to make select statement Dynamic ? Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list with data around 30+ properties for each List Item and i am trying to write a Linq Query which will do operations on the List .

My properties per say for each list item they're Name , place , Age etc so what if i want to filter my list to select specific columns data like only name or place or any combination .

**static query :**

```
(from data in myList select new {DName = data.Name,myPlace= data.Place}).ToList();
```

so i'm looking to make `select` part dynamic . All my required columns info i will store in a array

**Example :**

```
var arr = new [] {'Name','Age'} // this will change
```

Any ideas how to use my array of columns in lInq to filter data .

Comment: Where will it be changed, and who or what by?

Comment: @DaveWilliams is real scenario it's grid column customization . so user can select required columns for next time load and he saves it to db so i get the saved list and i want filter the list contains which all column data so i can do a export of only customized columns .

Comment: In which case, would you not be better of dynamically altering the display? For example with WPF that would be the [AutoGeneratingColumns](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.autogeneratingcolumn(v=vs.110).aspx) event.

Answer (score 1):

You can try Dynamic LINQ, a concept introduced by Microsoft in one of their samples. There are several Nuget packages (e.g., https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Dynamic/). Basically, instead of strongly typed expressions, you have strings. You can find a post about it here: https://weblogs.asp.net/ricardoperes/dynamic-linq.

Comment: yeah i gone trough this particular one mentioned but still hoping there is something we can do without any additional package

Comment: Did you see my other post, https://weblogs.asp.net/ricardoperes/dynamic-linq-in-an-assembly-near-by?

Answer (score 1):

You can use ExpandoObject and add your string array as its properties.
You should declare new `ExpandoObject` and cast it to `IDictionary<String,Object>`, Then get each property of your data row using reflection and by property name from string array. Finally add property name and its value to casted dictionary.

## example:

```
//initialize DataSource  
var myList = Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Select (i=>  new { Name = "abc", Place = "def" }).ToList();  

//initialize array of properties  
var properties = new string[] { "Name", "Place" };  
var result = myList.Select(data =>    
{  
    dynamic r = new System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject();  
    properties.AsParallel().ForAll(   
        p => (r as IDictionary<string, object>).Add(p,   
        data.GetType().GetProperty(p).GetValue(data, null)));  
    return r;  
});  
Console.WriteLine(result.Last().Place); //def
```

Comment: let me give a shot